# Large number of operations on double data type producing zero as result

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I have a program which multiplies a probability over 500 times, but when I am doing so the output is zero. Should I use some other data type?
Please help.
Here is the code I am using:

```
double d = 1/80000d;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        d *= d;
    }
    System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: If you really need to compute *d^500* or whatever it is, there are easier ways to do it, and indeed in this case the result is a constant, but the result still won't be representable within the precision of a `double.` Are you sure this is what you need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is zero because `double` has a limited percision, and if you multiply a number lower than 1 by itself enough times, you'll get a result too small to be distinguished from 0.

If you print `d` after each iteration, you'll see that it becomes 0 quite fast :

```
1.5625E-10
2.4414062500000002E-20
5.960464477539064E-40
3.552713678800502E-79
1.2621774483536196E-157
1.593091911E-314
0.0
```

Comment: What should I do to keep the precision?

Comment: @AnkitAnand Try using BigDecimal

Comment: Before doing that, check that you really do need to represent numbers that small.

Answer (score 1):

When working with probabilities, you can avoid these sort of numerical issues by working instead with logarithms, so that you can work additively. Something like

```
double d = 1/80000d;
double ld = Math.log(d)
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    ld += ld;
}
System.out.println(ld);
```

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, if you have two numbers less than 1, and repeated the multiply times sooner or later will be small enough to not be able resepresented in Double, Extended, or any floating arithmetic it done in the future. ;)

What your turn is the aproximation that has been stored in the type. ZERO is one of the special constants of IEEE 754 format.

I do not know JAVA, but exist the type Extended in other languages.